# Windows Server 2003 - Grant Log on as a Service Right

Tags: windows-server-2003

On Windows Server 2003, how do you grant a user account permission to log on as a service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this Technet article:

["Add the Log on as a service right to an account"](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc739424%28WS.10%29.aspx)

Comment: Great, thanks!  I wonder why Google didn't just return that.

Answer (score 1):

I found it for a local user at least.  Under Administrative Tools, open Local Security Policy.  Expand the Local Policies folder and select User Rights Assignment.  In the right pane, double click "Log on as a Service."  You can then use that dialog box to grant or revoke the privilege from users and groups.

Comment: See my link for further details